# How to make WP get_terms orderby array

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

How can I sort terms using two values?
I'm using this:

```
        $papers = get_terms(
          array(
            'taxonomy' => 'paper',
            'hide_empty' => false,

            'orderby'    => array(
                'year' => 'DESC',
                'number' => 'DESC'
           ),
           'order' => 'DESC'
        ));
```

But I know `get_terms` doesn't accept array for `orderby`.
I've searched a lot but there are not valid solutions or maybe I didn't find the right one.

What can I try?

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_terms_orderby` filter from wordpress

check these references.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_terms_orderby/

http://hookr.io/filters/get_terms_orderby/

https://wp-kama.com/hook/get_terms_orderby